# Bulk update of which fields synchronize from Sales Cloud in multiple objects

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder

We are using Marketing Cloud Connect to bring data from Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud. Currently we are synchronizing almost 20 different objects with numerous fields, as this data is needed for many journeys in our account.

Recently we evaluated all the data that we bring to Marketing Cloud and in order to decrease the amount of data, we have decided to stop synching many fields which are not used in journeys, and add a few additional ones that we will need.

When I did a comparison in Excel of what we currently synchronize, and what we actually need, I found that there is almost 1000 fields in total that need to be updated for multiple objects.

I cannot find a way to update this is bulk, and doing it manually in Contact Builder seems very time consuming.

Does anyone have any idea how this could be done in bulk?

Comment: What do you mean by '1000 fields in total that need to be updated'? the values of the fields? if yes, you can use journey builder to update it.

Comment: no, I mean which field sare getting synchronized. not values, but fields.

Comment: Not available to my knowledge! I believe this can be put as an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) which will certainly help in administration with the initial synchronization settings.